# Is there simpler way?

Tags: c++, stl

I'd like to know if there is a shorter / simpler way to:

1. Split the incoming string by words
2. Write the tokens in reverse order to stdout

There are two restrictions: no libraries and no loops

```
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <deque>

void list_string_elements(std::string s) {
    using namespace std;

    istringstream iss (s);
    deque<string> v;

    copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss), istream_iterator<string>(), front_inserter(v));

    copy(v.begin(),v.end(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout,"\n"));
}
```

Comment: Looks nice to me...

Comment: @Armen: well, in Python it would be `print '\n'.join(reversed(s.split()))`, but yeah, it's nice *for C++* ;-)

Comment: Why is there a requirement for no loops? Just curious.

Comment: @Hunter: Because it was an exam task and our prof is very keen on avoiding loops where the same can be achieved with pure STL.

Comment: It's quite intereting why your deque is called `v` rather than `d` :)

Comment: @cimnine: great to see there are real C++ teachers in the wild and not just "C with classes" teachers.

Comment: @Alexandre: I hope he's teaching us right. After all he claims to be in the C++0x standards committee ;)

Comment: @cimnine: He is in the committee? What is his name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slight abbreviation, we can get rid of a copy thanks to the iterator constructor of `deque`:

```
void list_string_elements(std::string s) {
    using namespace std;

    istringstream iss (s);
    deque<string> v(istream_iterator<string>(iss), (istream_iterator<string>()));
    copy(v.rbegin(),v.rend(),ostream_iterator<string>(cout,"\n"));
}
```

Note the extra parens around `istream_iterator<string>()`, to avoid a most vexing parse.

Comment: Can't you even put the stream declaration into the deque declaration?

Comment: @Christian: yes you can, just replace `iss` with `istringstream(s)`, but it would go off the RHS of SO's code window. Funny how obsolete restrictions on coding style can come back into fashion ;-) With a suitable range-like class and matching `copy` function you could avoid naming `v` too, but that's either a lot of typing to set up the one-liner, or else it breaks the rules of the question by using Boost.Range.

Answer (score 5):

There is not, because you need to store the words until the last one is fetched. It is more complex to try to tokenize backwards.

Also you cannot use `std::copy_backward` because `std::istream_iterator` is not bidirectional (only input).

`std::deque` is perfect for this task. You could have also used `vector` + `back_inserter`, and copied from `v.rbegin()` to `v.rend()` into `ostream_iterator`.

Also, the logic of tokenizing the string is simplest expressed with `istringstream`.

Basically, this looks like one cannot do much better.

The only religious little thing is that I cannot stand `using namespace`, even at block scope.

My proposal, with same number of lines:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void output_tokens(const std::string& str)
{
    typedef std::istream_iterator<std::string> in_iterator;
    typedef std::ostream_iterator<std::string> out_iterator;

    std::istringstream in(str);
    std::vector<std::string> buffer(in_iterator(in), (in_iterator()));
    std::copy(buffer.rbegin(), buffer.rend(), out_iterator(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

**Important edit:** You need the extra pair of parentheses around `in_iterator()` to avoid the entire statement to be parsed as a function declaration. @Steve Jessop's answer has the same issue. See [this erroneous sample](http://www.ideone.com/EVvGh) to witness the hair-pulling error message that results from such confusion.

Comment: About the `using namespace`: To fill the method body was an exercise in an exam. The method frame was given, including the `using namespace`. But I agree with you.

Comment: That is indeed religious (that is, firmly believed but based on absolutely nothing :)

Comment: @Armen: this can be debated, because every form of `using namespace` can have nasty effects. So it's more theologic than religious, ie. based on a book that has some undisputed authority :)

Comment: @Alexandre: Having premarital sex can have very nasty effects as well.  And you won't ***die*** if you refrain from it. But... :)

Comment: In your code, you've declared `buffer` as a function that returns a vector, and takes as parameters an `in_iterator` (named `in`), and a pointer to a function taking no parameters and returning `in_iterator`. The second parameter is unnamed. Most Vexing Parse.

Comment: @Armen: Using namespace isn't as fun as premarital sex.

Comment: @Steve: corrected (before your comment actually). I figured it out when I ran the code in ideone... Vexing, indeed.

Comment: @Alexandre: heh, you were probably fixing it while I was working out what the declared type actually was... The part of the hair-pulling error message to focus on is "which is of non-class type" - if you think you've defined an object of class type, but in fact it has non-class type, then pretty much always it's because of a vexing parse. You can then closely examine the rest of the message to confirm that it is a function type, or ignore that entirely.

Comment: @Steve: the error message is accurate. It is just vexing to parse... If you never encountered the MVP, you will have quite a hard time figuring out what is going on actually.

Comment: @Alexandre: sure, I agree, I'm just saying that the way to cope with that message is to you train yourself to read "which is of non-class type" as meaning, "have another look at that definition, it doesn't say what you think it says". And you're right, without knowing what the problem is the error message is pretty difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2):

It's good that your teacher is encouraging use of proper C++ functionality, but for fun, I would contend that using `copy` is simply moving the loop further down the stack... I would contend that recursion is the real way of doing this without using an explicit loop, something like below...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator;

void print_reverse(iterator s, iterator i, iterator e)
{
  // last word
  if (i == e)
  {
    if (s != i)
      std::cout << std::string(s, i) << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  std::string word;
  if (*i == ' ')
  {
    // have word here
    word.assign(s, i);
    s = ++i;
  }
  else
    ++i;
  // recursively call   
  print_reverse(s, i, e);

  if (!word.empty())
    std::cout << word << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
  std::string foo ("foo bar bof bob");
  print_reverse(foo.begin(), foo.begin(), foo.end());
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to feel about this. This has obvious problems (the first being that it isn't tail recursive, and thus will unneccessarily fail on long strings, the second being that the signature of the function isn't descriptive). On the other hand, it seems correct, but very verbose. The answers presented so far have the obvious advantage that they have production quality stardards.

Comment: @Alexandre, it's not meant for any production use, simply being pedantic about loops... Tbh, in production quality code you're unlikely to have such artificial constraints. It's purely for demonstration of concept...

Comment: abstracting away the loops in favor of named "algorithms" makes code more readable and thus more easily maintainable. Those constraints are not at all artificial in modern C++.